# Find which object is not in a list, but with possible duplicates... tricky

Tags: python, list, duplicates, set

The title isn't really clear, but it's hard to describe the issue I've been running into.

Let's consider a `Signal` class with the `==` and `!=` method implemented. (it is a simplified version of mine).

```
import numpy as np

class Signal:

    def __init__(self, fq, t0, tf):
        """
        Creation of the object.
        """
        # Amplitude and shape
        self.amp = float(8)

        # Timing and frequency
        self.t0 = t0
        self.tf = tf
        self.duration = round(self.tf - self.t0, 3)
        self.fq = fq                                 
        self.timeline = np.round(np.arange(t0, tf, 1/fq*1000), 3)

    def __eq__(self, s):
        """ == comparison method."""
        return self.fq == s.fq and self.t0 == s.t0 and self.tf == s.tf

    def __ne__(self, s):
        """ != comparison method."""
        return not self.__eq__(self, s)
```

Now let's consider this 2 list of Signal objects:

```
t0 = 0
tf = 200
desired_n = [Signal(20, t0, tf), Signal(30, t0, tf), Signal(40, t0, tf)]
desired_n_minus_1 = [Signal(20, t0, tf), Signal(30, t0, tf)]
```

To find which signal is not in `desired_n_minus_1` I simply loop and check:

```
for s in desired_n:
    if s not in desired_n_minus_1:
         signal_missing = s
         break
```

Perfect it works! However... here is the trick: I can have the same signal several times in the list `desired_n`. Example:

```
t0 = 0
tf = 200
desired_n = [Signal(20, t0, tf), Signal(30, t0, tf), Signal(30, t0, tf)]
desired_n_minus_1 = [Signal(20, t0, tf), Signal(30, t0, tf)]
```

In this case my solution don't work anymore, and I need the program to return `Signal(30, t0, tf)`. I don't care which one of the 2 it returns.

And that's not it, there a worst case:

```
t0 = 0
tf = 200
desired_n = [Signal(20, t0, tf), Signal(20, t0, tf), Signal(30, t0, tf), Signal(30, t0, tf)]
desired_n_minus_1 = [Signal(20, t0, tf), Signal(30, t0, tf), Signal(30, t0, tf)]
```

In this case I need one of the 2 `Signal(20, t0, tf)` to be returned.

Usually when working with duplicates I use sets, however, I didn't implement (and never did once in my life) the hash method for the object...

Thanks for the help to find a trick around this issue :)

Comment: In some Python versions (at least, in Python 3.6 if I'm not mistaken), Python will automagically provide you with a default version of `__hash__` for your class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `set` will not work in your case, since it will not keep track of the multiplicity of each element : in your second and third cases, you would have:

```
set(desired_n) == set(desired_n_minus_1)
```

What you can do instead is to loop on `desired_n_minus_1` and remove these elements from `desired_n`:

```
output = list(desired_n)
for u in desired_n_minus_1:
    output.remove(u)
```

Comment: Thanks, quite the best solution in my case. I found another one in the end ^^'

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can just implement `__hash__` by calling `hash()` on a tuple of the unique fields, for example:

```
class Signal:
    ...
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.fq, self.t0, self.tf))
```

And then:

```
>>> a = Signal(10, 20, 30)
>>> b = Signal(20, 30, 40)
>>> c = Signal(10, 20, 30)  # same as a
>>> s = {a, b, c}
>>> len(s)
2
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep it in mind for when I need a to implement sets :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can make sure that Signal is never alter after its creation, you can make a `__hash__` method by hashing the values you compare in `__eq__`:

```
 def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.fq, self.t0, self.tf))
```

Then you can use sets for duplicate elimination.

Answer (score 0):

Additional solution I found:

```
for s in desired_n:
    if s not in desired_n_minus_1:
        signal_missing = s
        break
    elif desired_n.count(s) > desired_n_minus_1.count(s):
        signal_missing = s
        break
    else:
        continue
```